# SQL Comparing a table with itself

Tags: sql

```
Movie(title, year, director, budget, earnings)
Actor(stagename, realname, birthyear)
ActedIn(stagename, title, year, pay)
CanWorkWith(stagename, director)
```

Find all pairs of stage names (renamed stagename1 and stagename2) such that the actor
with stagename1 acted in the same movie as the actor with stagename2, but earned less
for acting in that movie.

```
SELECT A.stagename, B.stagename
FROM ActedIn A
LEFT JOIN ActedIn B ON A.title = B.title AND A.year = B.year
          AND B.pay > A.pay
WHERE B.name IS NOT NULL
```

Not sure whether or not the WHERE B.name IS NOT NULL is valid

Comment: It's valid, but it'll basically convert the query into an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Is it `B.stagename IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @Eric please don't change the question once you get the answer. Up-vote the best answer or answers and select an "accepted answer" (click the check mark by the answer). Leaving the original question in place helps others who have the same issue find your question and the answers already given.

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67568/1

```
select a1.stagename as stagename1, a2.stagename as stagename2, a1.title
from ActedIn as a1
 inner join ActedIn as a2 on (a1.title = a2.title and a1.year = a2.year)
where a1.pay < a2.pay
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.stagename, B.stagename
FROM ActedIn A
INNER JOIN ActedIn B ON A.title = B.title 
AND A.year = B.year AND B.pay > A.pay
WHERE B.name IS NOT NULL
```

LEFT JOIN will be of no use if you dont want NULL values fron B.